# Remove all Array_Constrain(ArrayForumla(*),1,1) formulas when importing from Excel to Google Sheets using RegEx

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, regex

My first question here. I have an Excel Spreadsheet, where I have not used CSE, which I import into Google Sheets. Upon importing, some 40k+ cells have `=Array_Constrain(ArrayFormula(*),1,1)` in them. Except for two cells, in 1 sheet, across 50+ sheets, I do not need the formulas.

I spent over an hour, going sheet by sheet, to remove all "ArrayFormula". This left me with and extra set of () in the formulas, and I'm not looking forward to spending a few more hours removing all the Array_Constrains.

I'm wondering if someone can give me a CTRL+H and the RegEx expression to

1. convert '=Array_Constrain((other_functions)),1,1)' to just '=other_functions'
   and for next time
2. convert '=Array_Constrain(ArrayFormula(other_functions),1,1) to just '=other_functions'

Comment: The unprotected workbook is at https://TinyUrl.com/CovidHerdTracker. Please note, it takes a while to update, and if you want to experiment, feel free to test on it, using 'This Sheet' in the CTRL+H options. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: The sample spreadsheet is too large to be practical for testing. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @doubleunary, Thank you for the welcome. And yeah, I'm not exactly sure how the array formulas got into sheets.. which might be my second question ( in another post ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started, choose **Edit > Find and replace** (Control+*Shift*+H) and use something like this:

- **Find:** `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN\(\s*ARRAYFORMULA\(\s*(.+)\s*\), 1, 1\)`
- **Replace with:** `=$1`
- **Search:** `All sheets`
- **Match case**
- ☑️  **Search using regular expressions**
- ☑️  **Also search within formulas**
- **Replace all**

Then do the same with `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN\(\s*\(\s*(.+)\s*\)\s*\), 1, 1\)` and `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN\(\s*(.+)\s*\), 1, 1\)`.

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Comment: thank you. That solves my issue. Also, thank you for the links, and the $1 too :)